# how to add delay time in GUI java

Tags: java

so i have an array of JButtons of size 10 and all have the text "7" inside 
for example i click on button[0], suppose i want to increment the values inside buttons[1]-[7] ( i already done that) but how do I add a delay time so that i looks like an animation instead of when I click button[0] all the other button's values immediately changes.

I tried using other codes i found here in stack overflow such as thread.sleep(1000) and this link

http://best-programming-tricks.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-make-loading-delay-time-in-java.html

when i tried it on my codes, the GUI just goes into a lag then changes the values. it doesn't do what i want it to do

thank you

here is an example of my actionListener

```
buttons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                 int i = Integer.parseInt(buttons[0].getText());
                 setValuetoZero(0);
                 int delay = 1000;
                    for(int a =1; a<= i; a++){
                        int getVal = Integer.parseInt(buttons[a].getText());
                        getVal++;
                        String newVal = Integer.toString(getVal);
                        buttons[a].setText(newVal);
                    }
                }

             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use javax.swing.Timer.  You give the constructor an ActionLitener to be called at a given interval.  You can think of it almost as a hidden button which is pressed at every interval.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

The reason sleep causes the lag is that it is causing the thread which the GUI is running in to go to sleep.  This means that the GUI can no respond to input while it is sleeping.  For thread to sleep you would need to launch another thread and deal with synchronizing its access to data with the GUI which is probably way more trouble for you than it is worth.  That is why the Timer is good.  It will not interrupt the GUI and execute its ActionListener in the same thread as the GUI.

Comment: can i add this to my for loop?

Comment: No, I think you would want to put the for loop in the actionPerformed function which gets called by the timer.

Comment: yes my for loop is inside the actionPerformed function

Comment: i posted my actionlistener in the problem can you help me?

Comment: There must be no loop/sleep in actionPerformed(). The code in actionPerformed is executed in the GUI thread. You need to schedule the timer to be executed evey N milliseconds, and each time actionPerformed of the Timer is called, update the next button. When there is no button toupdate anymore, you need to stop the timer

Comment: i need to update the other buttons in a single click thats why the for loop is inside

Comment: Take some time to read that answer again and read my comment again. Take some time to read the javadoc of Timer and understand what it does. You don't need any loop, because the Timer does the loop for you: every N milliseconds, it calls actionPerformed(). And that's where you update the next button.